# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I open my project solution i get this error. What does this mean?
In the Solution explorer, everything shows load failed. I cannot edit or open any file of the solution in VS.

> **Error :**
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

I have already repair visual studio and ms build 2015

Answer (score 5):

Installing the .NET 3.5 development tools from the VS installer (individual components) tab fixed the issue for me.

Comment: this can be done with turning on the .NET 3.5 development tools in the Windows Program and Features

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core is a nuget package, this nuget package contains an assembly manifest and cannot run without it, it's the config file for the manifest.

Restore the nuges package and it will work just fine.

edit:

if this does not work try a workaround:

you can set an appSetting for your app `MSBUILD_PATH = D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` and that should get you unblocked.

**Note**

If anyone is using packages **from pre-release packages of ASP.NET**, they will also have to **add NuGet.config in the solution directory** to make ASP.NET 5.0 builds work as the package source is different from nuget.org

Comment: how to restore it? Sorry I am new to ASP.

Comment: Right click on references => manage nuget packages. It will tell you if something is in need to be restored.

Comment: Thats the problem, I cannot open any files in my solution, check out this: https://pasteboard.co/H3iIDG8.png

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: open the appSettings in notepad and try the workaround

Comment: No bro,I didnt find any appSetting file, I have Web.config.

Comment: Same thing :) Web.Config is the appSettings for asp.net

Comment: You have an appsetting tag inside, add msbuild_path configuration

Comment: Do you mean something like this: 

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    MSBUILD_PATH = D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
  </appSettings>

Comment: can we discuss on chat please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163302/discussion-between-sobmac-and-barr-j).