# Could not load assembly Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core Version=15.1.0.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a problem running a gulp task for transforming my config files. It reports following error:

```
error MSB4062: The "TransformXml" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsof t.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confi rm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

What the task does:

1. It creates a `_msbuild.proj` file with config file to be transformed. The file looks like this (obviously Source, Transform and Destination are filled in with real data):

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Demo" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>
    <Target Name="Transform">
        <TransformXml Source="" Transform="" Destination=""/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

2. The it runs this file against msbuild: `C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\msbuild.exe .\_msbuild.proj /t:Transform`

I have already seen [this answer which suggests it is a nuget package and might be corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294303/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-build-utilities-core). I don't think that's the case since everyone else in my project does not have this problem. Also I do have the problematic dll - `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core` however in a higher version (16.4.0) installed in various places along with dotnet and VS installation.

The only difference I see is that I am using VS 2019 and have the `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll` (a library which contains TransformXml taks and depends on missing library) in different location on disk than it is in the gulp transform module - I have it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio` while others have it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild`

I am stuck on this problem for almost a day now and cannot move a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Could not load assembly Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core
>   Version=15.1.0.0

I think the issue is that you used the `msbuild.exe` of Framework version rather than msbuild of VS2019.

**And** `C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319\\msbuild.exe .\_msbuild.proj /t:Transform` means that you use the msbuild of Framework.

**To explain it more detailed**:

**MSBuild of VS2019** integrates with a variety of vs environment parameters, is directly related to your various operations in vs, and the framework's msbuild only has the most basic compilation project function which does not have `TransformXml` task.

**Besides**, `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll` is just a part of msbuild of VS2019 so that it can be recognized by msbuild of VS2019. But this dll is not under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\xxxx`, so use Framework's msbuild cannot get what you want.

**Solution**

As a workaround, you should use MSBuild of VS2019 to correspond to `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll` which exists in its folder.

**1)** use  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` to execute `_msbuild.proj`.

**2)** Or just use [Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs)

And I think anyone else also used this msbuild.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: I think the problem in my case is the entire gulp setup. Based on your answer I have found out that gulp supports VS 2017 but apparently not 2019 and this might be a problem. Other people who are longer in the project do not have this problem and one guy who joined just before me is also having it. So I guess it's a gulp issue. I will mark your answer as correct as it provides explanation on why this might be happening.

Comment: I have the same error message and I'm already using the developers command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for this, very useful. My MSBuild.exe for VS2019 community was here though: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error happend when my script tried to use and old version of Nuget to restore packages.

I donwloaded Nuget 5.5, which is the one compatible with VS 2019 (you can see it in the Help > About of VS2019) and the problem dissapeared.

You can download it from:
https://www.nuget.org/downloads